# R shiny: Edit the format of a table output

Tags: r, shiny

I am outputting a table using shiny (with renderTable and tableOutput), is there a way to edit the format of the table and of the values within the table.

Specifically I want to

- Use comma as 1000 superator (i.e. change 1234567 to 1,234,567)
- Put a £ sign before every value in **one** column
- Make the final row bold
- Remove row names

So if you take the shiny reactivity e.g. as an example

```
runExample('03_reactivity')
```

This outputs a table 'view', the server.R code for it is

```
  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput(), n = input$obs)
  })
```

The ui.R code for it is

```
tableOutput("view")
```

In this example I would want to output

```
area    peri        shape   perm
£4,990  2,791.90    0.09    6.30
£7,002  3,892.60    0.15    6.30
£7,558  3,930.66    0.18    6.30
£7,352  3,869.32    0.12    6.30
£7,943  3,948.54    0.12    17.10
£7,979  4,010.15    0.17    17.10
£9,333  4,345.75    0.19    17.10
£8,209  4,344.75    0.16    17.10
£8,393  3,682.04    0.20    119.00
£6,425  3,098.65    0.16    119.00
```

(With the header remaining bold and the bottom row also in bold, turns out stackoverflow is equally difficult to get in the format I want ;))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi I have added comments in my answer, hopefully this would help. Look in to [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) here for more information how to customize your tables.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(scales)

# Sample Data
area <- seq(from=10,to=100, by=10)
peri <- seq(from=2710.1,to=2800.1, by=10)
shape <- seq(from=0.1,to=1, by=0.1)
perm <- seq(from=1,to=100, by=10)
my_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(area,peri,shape,perm))

ui = fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("view"),
      #4 Make the final row bold using tags$style
      tags$style(type="text/css", "#view tr:last-child {font-weight:bold;}")
    ),
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {
  output$view <- renderTable({
    test <- my_data
    #1 Comma Seperator as 1000: you can use the library(scales) and the comma function
    test$peri<-comma(test$peri)
    #2 Out the "£" sign before every value in column 1 (or any column): you can use paste0
    test$area <- paste0("£",test$area)
    test
    #3 Remove row names : use inlcude.rownames=FALSE
  },include.rownames=FALSE)

}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: You may take a look at the DT package if you want to work with DataTables: https://github.com/rstudio/DT

Comment: Oh this is sweet, I didn't know about this package and most of the things I do on the datatable is with tags$style or tags$scrip, Cheers for that